# Remove intersecting geometry from multiple objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

This is kind of hard to explain using words. Basically, I want to remove the intersecting part of a model for both objects. Sort of like the exclude function in Adobe Illustrator's pathfinder panel, but in 3d space.
[image]

I have a way that I've been doing it that takes way to long for how many times I need to replicate it. Here's how:

1. Use an intersect boolean to find where the two meshes intersect.
2. Duplicate the object with the boolean modiefier.
3. Remove the boolean modifier from the first object.
4. Apply the boolean modifier to the duplicated object. (I'll refer to it now as the intersect mesh)
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and set Origin to Geometry. Then scale up the intersect mesh by a tiny amount. If I skip this step, step 6 results in this ugly mess:
   [image: Difference boolean without scaling]
6. Add a difference boolean modifier to both of the original objects and apply them both.

The end result is this:
[image: Final result]
Another possible solution would be to duplicate both objects and boolean the original two to their opposite duplicates, which takes just as long as the first way and it's a lot harder to keep track of object names.

Both processes take way to long and are very cumbersome. Is there any way to do this

- Quicker
- More accurately
- With a greater amount of Objects (remove the intersections of all of them combined)

Comment: It would take some serious scripting to do this automatically over multiple objects.  I don't know of an Add-On to allow you to do this.  I will say though, your first process is more complicated than it needs to be.  (A.) Create two objects (B.) duplicate [Object1] (C.) Add Boolean to [Object1-Dup] (D.) Apply Boolean (E.) Add Boolean to [Object2] (F.) Apply Boolean. (G.) Delete [Object1].  In other words, you can cut out your step 3, 5, and 6.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply. Do you know of any way to do this with another program besides blender?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't.  A script to do this for a pair of objects may not be that complicated.

Comment: Alright. I know some pretty basic python, so I might be able to whip something up. Don't know about performing the same function with more than 2 objects, though. My guess is that it'll require a lot more booleans, and that'll definitely cause more problems. Thanks again for the support

Comment: For multiple object, you would need some kind of intersection detection (for deciding which objects to Boolean) and when more than two intersect with the same object, you'll probably need some kind of recursive algorithm.